# Valdating Varchar column contains valid date and also validate leap year or not in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_TEST(DD VARCHAR2(40));

Insert into DATE_TEST VALUES('30-02-24');
Insert into DATE_TEST VALUES('12-01-24');
INSERT INTO DATE_TEST VALUES('15');
```

I Want to list out the invalid rows from the above table in SQL.

so the expected OUTPUT

```
DD
-
30-02-24
15
```

Comment: Why don't you hold the `dd` column as in the `date` format ? Oracle already handles formatting issue for us.

Comment: Is the range of invalid dates defined or limited in some way? Because it's impossible to tell whether `13-01-24` is a valid European date or an invalid American date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12.2, you can use `TO_DATE` with `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` and then check if the converted value is `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   date_test
WHERE  TO_DATE(dd DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'DD-MM-RR') IS NULL
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| DD |
| --- |
| 30-02-24 |
| 15 |

In earlier versions, create a user-defined function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_Valid_Date(
  datestr VARCHAR2,
  format  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'FMDD-MM-RR'
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
AS
  x DATE;
BEGIN
  IF datestr IS NULL THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
  x := TO_DATE( datestr, format );
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   date_test
WHERE  is_valid_date(dd) = 0
```

Which outputs the same.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kNfGTOiC)

Comment: i am using oracle 12c

Comment: so above it is not working

Comment: @Ram "It is not working" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us "what" is not working. The fiddle linked in the answer shows that is does work if your Oracle version supports the syntax. What is your full Oracle version and what does "it is not working" mean?

Comment: I am using oracle 12 c. I ran the above query in my environment, it is showing missing right parenthesis. I think it is not supported in Oracle 12 c.

Comment: @Ram It was [introduced Oracle 12.2](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/conversion-function-enhancements-12cr2) (which is why I asked for your full Oracle version).

Comment: ok. Thank you. Mine is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.